# Count Down app Animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I am creating Countdown app. i finished all codes and its all working pretty fine but i am new to android animation. I need to apply below animation to my app. i tried use slide in/out but it is not working good i also tried few other animation but nothing is same as compared below animation.

once play button pressed a timer starts then once again pressed a pause button comes and a `textView` under pause icon which we have current countdown time. if again pressed the count start again. I am only looking for animation all other codes i have already done.
i have a `ImageButton` which shows icon each timer user press play/pause and `TextView` which shows countdown timer and another `TextView` which shows current timer when user press pause button.Is there anyway i can implement this animation to app?

So Any help would be appropriated as i am new to android animations. Thanks!

Here is xml:

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="228dp"
        android:layout_height="228dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/circlea"
        android:visibility="visible"

        android:background="@drawable/circle">

 <ImageButton
     android:layout_width="142dp"
     android:layout_height="142dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
    android:id="@+id/play"
     android:background="#000"
     android:layout_marginRight="43dp"
     android:src="@mipmap/icon"
     android:visibility="visible" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="134dp"
            android:layout_height="73dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="55sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
            android:id="@+id/countText"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:background="#000"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/pusetext"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#1EFFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="61dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

java:

```
//some code
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
play=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play);
pausetext=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.pusetext);
CountText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.countText);
play.OnClickListener startListener = new View.OnClickListener() {//first public void onClick( View v ){
 play.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 CountText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

ObjectAnimator slideDownAnimTextView = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(CountText, "translationY", -(CountText.getTop() + CountText.getHeight()), 0);
            slideDownAnimTextView.start();
}
CountText.setOnClickListener
 public void onClick( View v ){//pause click
play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
ObjectAnimator slideDownAnimPlayButton = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(play, "translationY", -(play.getTop() + play.getHeight()), 0);

            ObjectAnimator scaleDownAnimTextViewX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(CountText, "scaleX", 1f, 0.5f);
            ObjectAnimator scaleDownAnimTextViewY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(CountText, "scaleY", 1f, 0.5f);
            AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
            animatorSet.setDuration(1000);
            animatorSet.playTogether(slideDownAnimPlayButton,scaleDownAnimTextViewX,scaleDownAnimTextViewY);
            animatorSet.start();
}
 play.setOnClickListener
public void onClick(View view) {resume click
play.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            CountText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
CountText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() //pause click agine
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

//some code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [HTextView](https://github.com/hanks-zyh/HTextView) library to achieve the first part of the animations(showing the text).
Then, use `ObjectAnimator`s to slide and scale the text down, and to slide the play button down (Use `AnimatorSet` to play them all together).

Here's a sample code (you should, of course, change the values according to your needs) -

```
ObjectAnimator slideDownAnimPlayButton = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(play, "translationY", -(CountText.getTop()), 0); 
ObjectAnimator slideDownAnimTextView = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(CountText, "translationY",0, (CountText.getTop() )); 
ObjectAnimator scaleDownAnimTextViewX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(CountText, "scaleX", 1f, 0.5f); 
ObjectAnimator scaleDownAnimTextViewY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(CountText, "scaleY", 1f, 0.5f);
AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
animatorSet.setDuration(1000);
animatorSet.playTogether(slideDownAnimPlayButton,slideDownAnimTextView,scaleDownAnimTextViewX,scaleDownAnimTextViewY);
animatorSet.start();
```

Edit: Seeing your new code now, the problem with the first text animation is that you call it from `onCreate()`, so the View hasn't been drawn yet, meaning he does not have valid Height or Top parameters.
You can solve it by giving your animation a small delay, or using a `ViewTreeObserver`. See the following examples -

Starting your animation with a delay -

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ObjectAnimator slideDownAnimTextView = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(CountText, "translationY", -(CountText.getTop() + CountText.getHeight()), 0);
        slideDownAnimTextView.start();
    }
}, 300);
```

Or, perhaps the better way, use a `ViewTreeObserver` -

```
CountText.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        CountText.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        ObjectAnimator slideDownAnimTextView = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(CountText, "translationY", -(CountText.getTop() + CountText.getHeight()), 0);
        slideDownAnimTextView.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: Edited GIF please have a look. Thanks

Comment: It's a bit unclear now, but it seems you just need to reverse the second part of the animation. I'd suggest using `objectAnimtor.reverse()` for that.

Comment: what property's i can use to scale a TextView with objectAnimtor for sliding down animation? a code is very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: I am sorry what will be the startValue and endValue for this animation?

Comment: i am too noobie in animations. how does floating value effect on start and end point? please answer thanks also i can accept your answer after i done this. you were so helpful!

Comment: I edited my answer again. Please let me know if its not wokring for you, as I don't have your layout setup, so I can't really test it.

Comment: i tried but the countdown wont moving down to pause time . i edited question with my code for more clarification. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124566/discussion-between-tofira-and-fajar-khan).